# Overriding @JsonTypeInfo not working when using it for class field like List<Animal> where Animal is annotated with it

Tags: json, jackson

Friends,

I am facing issues in overriding **@JsonTypeInfo** annotation in specific scenarios.

Please find my class structures as below.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,    
property = "@type")
class Animal {
    public String name = "animalName";

    /**
     * @return the name
     */ 
    public String getName() {
   return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     *            the name to set
     */

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

}

class Cat extends Animal {
boolean likesCream = true;
public int lives = 10;

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
return "Cat [likesCream=" + likesCream + ", lives=" + lives + ", name="
    + name + "]";
}

/**
 * @return the likesCream
 */
public boolean isLikesCream() {
return likesCream;
}

/**
 * @param likesCream
 *            the likesCream to set
 */
public void setLikesCream(boolean likesCream) {
this.likesCream = likesCream;
}

/**
 * @return the lives
 */
public int getLives() {
return lives;
}

/**
 * @param lives
 *            the lives to set
 */
public void setLives(int lives) {
this.lives = lives;
}

}

class Dog extends Animal {
public double barkVolume; // in decibels

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
@Override
public String toString() {
return "Dog [barkVolume=" + barkVolume + ", name=" + name + "]";
}

/**
 * @return the barkVolume
 */
public double getBarkVolume() {
return barkVolume;
}

/**
 * @param barkVolume
 *            the barkVolume to set
 */
public void setBarkVolume(double barkVolume) {
this.barkVolume = barkVolume;
}
```

}

Now I am using above classses in my **Zoo** class which I need to serialize/deserialize.

```
class Zoo2i {

    List<Animal> animals;

    Dog dog;

    /**
     * @return the animals
     */
    public List<Animal> getAnimals() {
    return animals;
    }

    /**
     * @param animals
     *            the animals to set
     */
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,    
                 property = "@type")
   public void setAnimals(List<Animal> animals) {
   this.animals = animals;
   }

    /**
     * @return the dog
     */
    public Dog getDog() {
    return dog;
    }

    /**
     * @param dog
     *            the dog to set
     */
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,    
                  property = "@type")
     public void setDog(Dog dog) {
    this.dog = dog;
    }
}
```

As I have annotated Animal class , it will add type info by default to all its subclasses to support polymorphism.

List can have all types e.g Animal, Dog , Cat.
My requirement is that I do not want type information for Animal instance itself in List and for other property of type Dog in zoo2i class.

I am succeeded in overriding annotation for setDog(....) but failed for setAnimals(...) (plz see Zoo2i class).

Is there any different way to exclude type information for annotated class itself or to make type information optional(not mandatory) during deserialization.

One more thing that by default , Animal and all its instances are used, type info is included as Animal is annotated, I want that only when I use directly Cat , Dog then type information should not be included and should not be expected during deserialization;

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a supported use case: you should either use `@JsonTypeInfo` on base type to use, OR on property (for unannotated types). Don't try mixing approaches. Either a type should include type information or not -- trying to do it one way in some case, other in others sounds like a dangerous micro-optimization.

Comment: Yes , but i need to achieve that.I just want that when Animal animal = animal, means when value and declaring field both are of same type then type-info should not be considered in serialization/deserialization, for polymorphic and any other type , it should be.

Comment: Ok, good luck with that then! FWIW, deserialization can succeed, as long as you define 'defaultImpl' to be the base class itself.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering the same. but i don't know how to use **defaultImpl** of **@JsonTypeInfo** annotation to handle when type information is not present during deserialization. What method should I create in that class.....Please find my usage of annotation. @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class" ,defaultImpl = DefaultImpl.class) What should I write in **DefaultImpl** class

Comment: Nothing. If type info does not match, instance of default impl class is used, as if id did match. Just like any other matches. So you write DefaultImpl like any other `Animal` type. Jackson by default handles all details of type id.